# Data-binding is not updating ng-repeat section

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to angularjs and I have a data binding issue.

After each repeated line, I want to show a number of mutually exclusive options. These would be images using a background-image, and when the option is selected I add the css class 'selected' to the span containing the image.

I've simplified it below to show options A, B and C and to make the currently selected one bold. By clicking on A, B or C you change the option.

The inner ng-repeat section is not evaluated again (it seems) when the model changes, but as the "Debugging category" shows, the outer ng-repeat is re-evaluated and the "Debugging category" shows correctly that the category has been changed.

I'm clearly missing something about angularjs; how can I get the inner ng-repeat to re-evaluate to that the correct style is applied to the A, B and C options?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('NamesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.categories = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ];
    $scope.names = [
        { name: 'John', category: 'C' },
        { name: 'Cindy', category: 'A' },
        { name: 'Patrick', category: 'B' }
    ];

    $scope.changeCategory = function(name, category) {
        name.category = category;
    };
});
</script>
<body ng-app="testApp">
<h1>Names</h1>
<div ng-controller="NamesCtrl">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="name in names">
    <span>{{name.name}}</span>
    <span ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-init="selected = (category == name.category)">
        <span ng-style="{'true': {'font-weight': 'bold'}, false: {}}[selected]" ng-click="changeCategory(name, category)">{{category}}</span>
    </span>
    <em>(Debugging category: {{name.category}})</em>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-init` expression is not watched and updated automatically whenever related scope property value changes, you could just solve this by removing ng-init and using the expression directly

```
<span ng-style="{'true': {'font-weight': 'bold'}}[category == name.category]"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('NamesCtrl', function ($scope) {
  
    $scope.categories = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ];
    $scope.names = [
        { name: 'John', category: 'C' },
        { name: 'Cindy', category: 'A' },
        { name: 'Patrick', category: 'B' }
    ];

    $scope.changeCategory = function(name, category) {
        name.category = category;
       
    };
  
});
</script>
<body ng-app="testApp">
<h1>Names</h1>
<div ng-controller="NamesCtrl">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="name in names">
    <span>{{name.name}}</span>
    <span ng-repeat="category in categories" >
        <span ng-style="{'true': {'font-weight': 'bold'}}[category == name.category]" ng-click="changeCategory(name, category)">{{category}}</span>
    </span>
    <em>(Debugging category: {{name.category}})</em>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```